# Icon not showing in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, icons

I am using react-native-vector-icons library for showing icons in tabbar like shown below :

```
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<FontAwesome name='trophy' />
```

But it's not showing icon, so what to do for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icon display wrong because it can not find the font. I think you need to check if the bundle contains these .ttf files.

[image]

If not, [Here is the guide i found from docs](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/#option-manually-1)

The result of icon i tested with your code:

Code:
[image]

Result:
[image]